# Dynamically update part of Cached Page in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my MVC project, there is page which has static content except that it show the current time(which is dynamic).I want to Cache this page but due to time I can not.

I tried using DonutCatching, but it is not working.
Following is code which I tried using DonutCatching.

Main Controller:-Search.cs

```
[OutputCache(Duration=3600)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View("Main.cshtml");
}
public ActionResult Part()
{
     return View("Date.cshtml",DateTime.Now);
}
```

Main.cshtml

```
@using DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching;
<div></div>
<div></div>
@Html.Action("Part","Search",true)
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Date.cshtml

```
@model DateTime
<h2>@Model</h2>
```

I want to cache Main.cshtml but update part of date every time Main.cshtml is requested. Any solution or what am I doing wrong in above?

Comment: Why don't you simply use Javascript for that?

Comment: Javascript works fine but what if I want to show advertise instead of date then what will I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that could be possible because the entire page is cached server side. You could try an Ajax load based on a timer (kind of setTimeout js) or put a $.ready() handler instead of a partial view. Then load that section after the cached main page finish loading.
Check this function in jQuery: 
http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
<div id="dynamicsection">
<script>
$( "#dynamicsection" ).load( "@Url.Action("Part", "Search")");
</script>
```

Let me know if that helps